Percentile Aggregation in Elastic Search returns value 0 even though there are matching documents with values
I am trying to calculate 75th percentile value for pricingscore property thru aggregation in my Elastic Search query. And my last condition seem to return 0 docCount returning 0 percentile value.
This is the mapping of properties I have in my Index :
        "pricingbytrade" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "name" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "analyzed" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "analyzer" : "standard",
                    "search_analyzer" : "synonym_analyzer"
                  },
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256,
                    "normalizer" : "lowercase"
                  }
                }
              },
              "pricingbycbsa" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                  "cbsaid" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                  },
                  "cbsaname" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                  },
                  "pricingscore" : {
                    "type" : "float"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          } 

This is the code in my AggregationContainerDescriptor.
Here, pricingbytrade.name must match with the given searchterm and pricingbytrade.pricingbycbsa.cbsaid must match with given cbsaid for document to be matched and calculate 75th percentile of pricingbytrade.pricingbycbsa.pricingscore :
 .Nested("pricingbytrade", n => n
                .Path("pricingbytrade")
                .Aggregations(nestedAggs => nestedAggs
                    .Nested("pricingbycbsa", nn => nn
                        .Path("pricingbytrade.pricingbycbsa")
                        .Aggregations(nestedNestedAggs => nestedNestedAggs
                            .Filter("filter_bycbsa", ff => ff
                                .Filter(filter => filter
                                    .Bool(b => b
                                        .Should(filterList => filterList
                                          .Term(t => t
                                                .Field("pricingbytrade.pricingbycbsa.cbsaid")
                                                .Value(_cbsaId)
                                            ),
                                            filterList => filterList
                                                .Term(t => t
                                                    .Field("pricingbytrade.name")
                                                    .Value(_searchTerm.ToLower())
                                                )
                                       )
                                    )
                                )
                                .Aggregations(subAggs => subAggs
                                    .Percentiles("price_score_percentiles", p => p
                                        .Field("pricingbytrade.pricingbycbsa.pricingscore")
                                        .Percents(75)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );

I tried "must" instead of "should" inside bool but no difference.
I access my percentile value as below which always comes as 0 :
var priceScorePercentiles = response.Aggregations
                  .Nested("pricingbytrade")
                  .Nested("pricingbycbsa")
                  .Nested("filter_bycbsa")
                  .PercentilesBucket("price_score_percentiles")
                  .Items[0]
                  .Value;

Though there are matching documents, I get the docCount as 0 for price_score_percentiles bucket. Is there any mistake in code I have to correctly calculate percentile value where documents be picked only when both condition match ?

I'm trying to write a comment to you, but I guess I can't because of the Stack Overflow rules -_-. Anyway, I did the same thing you did, but I got results. I'll share what I did; maybe it can be useful for you.
First creating index with mapping:
PUT /new_stack_over_flow_question
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "pricingbytrade": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "pricingbycbsa": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "cbsaid": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "cbsaname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "pricingscore": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Second inserting dummy data
POST /new_stack_over_flow_question/_doc
{
  "pricingbytrade": {
    "name": "dummy_name1",
    "pricingbycbsa": [
      {
        "cbsaid": 123,
        "cbsaname": "dummy_cbsa_name1",
        "pricingscore": 10.5
      },
      {
        "cbsaid": 456,
        "cbsaname": "dummy_cbsa_name2",
        "pricingscore": 15.2
      }
    ]
  }
}

POST /new_stack_over_flow_question/_doc
{
  "pricingbytrade": {
    "name": "dummy_name2",
    "pricingbycbsa": [
      {
        "cbsaid": 789,
        "cbsaname": "dummy_cbsa_name3",
        "pricingscore": 20.1
      },
      {
        "cbsaid": 101,
        "cbsaname": "dummy_cbsa_name4",
        "pricingscore": 25.7
      }
    ]
  }
}



POST /new_stack_over_flow_question/_doc
        {
          "pricingbytrade": {
            "name": "dummy_name2",
            "pricingbycbsa": [
              {
                "cbsaid": 789,
                "cbsaname": "dummy_cbsa_name3",
                "pricingscore": 20.1
              },
              {
                "cbsaid": 101,
                "cbsaname": "dummy_cbsa_name4",
                "pricingscore": 25.7
              }
            ]
          }
        }

Here you can see all the data
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "new_stack_over_flow_question",
        "_id": "wFMHqY4BH07gFgTpzL-g",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "pricingbytrade": {
            "name": "dummy_name1",
            "pricingbycbsa": [
              {
                "cbsaid": 123,
                "cbsaname": "dummy_cbsa_name1",
                "pricingscore": 10.5
              },
              {
                "cbsaid": 456,
                "cbsaname": "dummy_cbsa_name2",
                "pricingscore": 15.2
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "new_stack_over_flow_question",
        "_id": "wVMIqY4BH07gFgTpar81",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "pricingbytrade": {
            "name": "dummy_name2",
            "pricingbycbsa": [
              {
                "cbsaid": 789,
                "cbsaname": "dummy_cbsa_name3",
                "pricingscore": 20.1
              },
              {
                "cbsaid": 101,
                "cbsaname": "dummy_cbsa_name4",
                "pricingscore": 25.7
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "new_stack_over_flow_question",
        "_id": "wlMLqY4BH07gFgTpA78p",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "pricingbytrade": {
            "name": "dummy_name2",
            "pricingbycbsa": [
              {
                "cbsaid": 789,
                "cbsaname": "dummy_cbsa_name3",
                "pricingscore": 20.1
              },
              {
                "cbsaid": 101,
                "cbsaname": "dummy_cbsa_name4",
                "pricingscore": 25.7
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Then doing the search
POST /new_stack_over_flow_question/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "pricingbytrade_nested": {
      "nested": { "path": "pricingbytrade"},
      "aggs": {
        "pricingbycbsa_nested": {
          "nested": {"path": "pricingbytrade.pricingbycbsa"},
          "aggs": {
            "filter_bycbsa": {
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "pricingbytrade.pricingbycbsa.cbsaid": {
                          "value": 123
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "pricingbytrade.name": {
                          "value": "Product 1"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    ]
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "price_score_percentiles": {
                  "percentiles": {
                    "field": "pricingbytrade.pricingbycbsa.pricingscore",
                    "percents": [75]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

and here is the response:
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "pricingbytrade_nested": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "pricingbycbsa_nested": {
        "doc_count": 6,
        "filter_bycbsa": {
          "doc_count": 1,
          "price_score_percentiles": {
            "values": {
              "75.0": 10.5
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

You can compare what I shared with you with the (response), or compare the calling (sourceBuilder) with the search query request. Use the debug tool to open the C# (sourceBuilder) data; it should look like the same search query that I used.
If you can't fix it, just share the (response) data and (sourceBuilder) data from your debugger. And I will help you to debug it.

Thank you @Hamza Alajlouni for your response. So with the data you posted on Index, if I make a search with cbsaid = 789 and name = trade_name1, I am expecting a doc_count of filter_bycbsa = 0 and percentile value as 0 since no doc is matching those name and cbsaid. I am getting percentile value as 20.100000381469727 which is incorrect for my usecase. If I change the query with "Must" instead of "Should", I am getting doc_count 0 and percentile "NaN" for cbsaid = 123 and name = trade_name1 which is also incorrect. We have a doc matching cbsaid = 123 and name = trade_name1.

Can you please show me how to fix the query that return doc_count that matches both the conditions and  calculate percentiles for those docs only ?

your search request is correct already, if you are using should, then the query will match (cbsaid == 789 OR name = trade_name1), in other words, if any of the conditions is true, then it is a match, when you use must then (cbsaid == 789 AND name = trade_name1), must mean that both of them have to be true, so when you use it, you are not getting any match, so doc_count 0 and percentile "NaN" is a correct result, and when you use should it will match all the documents that have the name = trade_name, plus all the documents that have cbsaid = 789, and of course, you will get matches in this case
